# probleme with the trace of Fork()

Tags: unix, process, fork, pid

I have this example of fork() I need to do a trace!

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        if (fork()) 
            wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

My solution for to do the trace is, something is wrong, I don't know how to do the trace:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

    int i,pid;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {

        pid=fork();

        if(pid>0) ///if is father (true)
            printf("PID After the fork child === %d  & father === %d (i = %d) \n\n",(int)getpid,(int)getppid,i);

        wait(NULL);

        printf(" After the wait  child=== %d  & father=== %d (i = %d)|||\n",(int)getpid,(int)getppid,i);
    }
}
```

This is what i get in the Terminal. I can see clearly that it is not correct, but i don't know how to resolve this problem:

```
PID After the fork child === 134513568  & father === 134513632 (i = 0) 

After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 0)|||
PID After the fork child === 134513568  & father === 134513632 (i = 1) 


After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 2)|||
After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 2)|||
After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 1)|||
PID After the fork child === 134513568  & father === 134513632 (i = 2) 

After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 2)|||
After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 2)|||
After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 0)|||
PID After the fork child === 134513568  & father === 134513632 (i = 1) 

After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 1)|||
PID After the fork child === 134513568  & father === 134513632 (i = 2) 

After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 2)|||
After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 2)|||
After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 1)|||
PID After the fork child === 134513568  & father === 134513632 (i = 2) 

After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 2)|||
After the wait  child=== 134513568  & father=== 134513632 (i = 2)|||
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the braces and brackets:

```
   if(pid>0) ///if is father (true) 
   {        
       printf("PID After the fork child === %d  & father === %d (i = %d) \n\n",(int)getpid(),(int)getppid(),i);

       wait(NULL);

      printf(" After the wait  child=== %d  & father=== %d (i = %d)|||\n",(int)getpid(),(int)getppid(),i);
  }
```

In your codes, the second `printf ("After the wait ...)` will be called in both parent process and child process.

Comment: no the braces its correct but i dont know why i get in the terminal the same value of the child in all iteration(from i=0 to i<3) and the same case of father???

Comment: @cleo: as @mah pointed out, you forget the put `()` after `getpid` and `getppid`. If you enable high warning level, the complier will prompt: `cast from '__pid_t (*)()throw ()' to 'int' loses precision`

Answer (score 1):

Your argument to `printf()` is `getpid` and `getppid` -- you're passing in the address of these functions, when it appears you intend to print the results of calling the functions. Call them...

```
printf("PID After the fork child === %d  & father === %d (i = %d) \n\n",(int)getpid(),(int)getppid(),i);
```